# Java: Maxed CPU Waiting on non-blocking queue

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following code:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        m = q.poll();
        if (m != null) {
            kf.sendMessage(m.topic, m.message);
        }
    }
}
```

where q is a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. Currently this is eating 100% of my CPU. Is there a more efficient way to wait on a non-blocking queue? I prefer to use a non-blocking queue because I am expecting bursty traffic from the producers on the queue, so I want to maximize performance. Is there a way to relinquish control of the cpu for my thread if q.poll() returns null?

I have the option of switching to a blocking queue, but I am curious what the proper way of doing this is.

Edit - Lots of good responses! Thanks for all your help. For now I'm going to just switch to a linkedblockqueue, and if I start running into performance issues re-evaluate.

Comment: relinquish control until when?

Comment: Since its a non blockking queue you might wanna sleep for say 5 msecs before you poll it again

Comment: Just to pass off control to the next thread? How would I sleep? Thread.sleep(5)? I thought that just pauses execution of the current thread but the CPU is not relinquished.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `BlockingQueue` of some type, which has methods for polling with a timeout (`poll`), or polling and waiting (`take`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have nothing else to do, and just want to wait (without using CPU) until data is available, then use a blocking queue. That's exactly what it's made for, with methods like [`take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html#take%28%29):

> Retrieves and removes the head of the queue represented by this deque (in other words, the first element of this deque), **waiting if necessary until an element becomes available**.

If you are interesting in how this is implemented, you can take a look at [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java) for these classes, for example `LinkedBlockingQueue#take`:

```
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
    E x;
    int c = -1;
    final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
    final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
    takeLock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count.get() == 0) {
            notEmpty.await();
        }
        x = dequeue();
        c = count.getAndDecrement();
        if (c > 1)
            notEmpty.signal();
    } finally {
        takeLock.unlock();
    }
    if (c == capacity)
        signalNotFull();
    return x;
}
```

As you can see, they maintain a couple of [Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to signal if the queue is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with bursty behavior, you could wait when you've checked the queue and it's empty.

```
while (true) {
    m = q.poll();
    if (m != null) {
        kf.sendMessage(m.topic, m.message);
    } else {
        // Queue was empty, wait for a little while
        // Adjust time based on your requirements
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

You should probably benchmark this to make sure it's actually faster than using a `BlockingQueue` though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) successors. In such case you do **not** need to **iterate** over empty list, thread **waiting** until next element in collection appears

---

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
       m = q.take();
       kf.sendMessage(m.topic, m.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your heart set on a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, you can do something along the lines of:

```
public void run() {
  while (true) {
    m = q.poll();
    if (m != null) {
        kf.sendMessage(m.topic, m.message);
    } else Thread.yield();
  }
}
```

More about [Thread.yield](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29). Also consider [sleeping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) for some small amount of time, say 50ms.